# CakePHP ACL Individual Object Access Control

Tags: php, cakephp, acl, access-control

I'm working on a project that requires one user to have many, say, posts. But, each user can only access his or her own posts. How can I accomplish this type of behavior with CakePHP's ACL component?

Currently, it seems that Cake's ACL is focused on actions and controllers rather than objects.

Any ideas (even switching to a different framework) would be awesome!

Thanks.

Comment: You can find answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030209/how-to-limit-data-to-users-who-own-it-without-limiting-admin-users-in-cakephp